# Add Cocoapods dependencies to my custom framework

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I'm trying to create a custom framework and require some cocoa pods to be bundled along with it.

I have tried adding my framework as the target in pod file, but it is still not working.

Comment: Could you please post the podspec?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|

    s.default_subspec = 'Base'

    s.subspec 'Base' do |ss|
        ss.dependency 'Crashlytics'
    end
end
```

More info here: [link](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#dependency)